# How to do the unit testing of history.push function?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to unit test the following element, especially the `onClick` function, But have no idea how to do the unit testing

```
const baseURL = "/Security/Users/";


return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex-between">
        <button
          className="bt-save"
          onClick={() => history.push(baseURL + "Add")}
        >
          Add
        </button>
       </div>
    </div>
  );
```

this is related to react unit testing using jest. From this, I want to unit test the Add Button `onClick` function.

Here is my approach to unit test this function

```
it('Should run the callback function when clicked', async () => {
    const onClick = jest.fn(baseURL + "Add")

    render(<button push={onClick}> Add </button>)

    const addButton = screen.getByText('Add')
    await userEvent.click(addButton)
    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to do the testing.

[I'm getting this result on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH7lq.png)

Can anyone help me understand this `onClick` function unit testing

Comment: I wanted to know the exact unit test for the onClick={() => history.push(baseURL + "Add")}

Answer (score 0):

You can accept an event callback as a prop of the component:

```js
        <button
          className="bt-save"
          onClick={() => props.onAdd()}
        >
```

Then you can unit test using React Testin Library:

```js
it("Should call onSave callback when clicking Add", async () => {
  const onAddMock = jest.fn();
  render(<MyComponent onAdd={onAddMock} />);

  await userEvent.click(screen.getByText("Add"));

  expect(onAddMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I'm trying this testing on the following function,
onClick={() => history.push(baseURL + "Add")}